# Use of android_media_Mediaplayer.cpp in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

While searching about internal details of video player, I came across a pdf where `MediaPlayer` class internally uses `android_media_Mediaplayer` for every message(i.e, `setDataSource()`, `prepare()`, `start()` etc.) and `android_media_MediaPlayer` calls `libmedia::MediaPlayer()` with same message. My question is why can't `MediaPlayer` class directly call `libmedia::MediaPlayer` instead calling through `android_media_MediaPlayer`?

Thank you!

The link of image is given below...

http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/2005/capturejij.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagram you linked to wasn't crystal clear, but I assume that the blue MediaPlayer box refers to the MediaPlayer Java class.

The libmedia MediaPlayer is a native class. Calls between Java and C/C++ need to go through the Java Native Interface (JNI), so android_media_MediaPlayer contains the necessary JNI code to communicate with the MediaPlayer Java class, thereby acting as a sort of proxy between the Java class and the native libmedia class.

For example, in MediaPlayer.java you'll find this delcaration:

```
public native void prepareAsync() throws IllegalStateException;
```

Which is listed in android_media_MediaPlayer as a JNINativeMethod:

```
{"prepareAsync", "()V", (void *)android_media_MediaPlayer_prepareAsync},
```

This says that the method which Java knows as "`prepareAsync`" has the signature "`()V`" (no arguments, returns `void`) and corresponds to the native function `android_media_MediaPlayer_prepareAsync`.
 When `android_media_MediaPlayer_prepareAsync` is called, it in turn calls the native MediaPlayer's `prepareAsync` method.